# How to include a default value for an external variable in BaseX

Tags: xquery, basex

I'm using the BaseX REST API to run xQuery files.

Parameters can be passed in via query strings:

```
declare variable $param1 as xs:string external;
```

However, I could not find out how to set a default value for a parameter.
Is this even possible?

thanks! 
Max

Comment: I can't mark your *comment* as "solving the problem" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XQuery, for such a variable declaration you can define a default by using e.g. `declare variable $param1 as xs:string external := 'foo';`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-variable-declarations.